# Database Refactoring in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, refactoring

I need to refactor the data model for a Rails application. This will involve consolidating two models (DB tables) into one. What would be the right way to do it? Will it be ok to delete a model? I assume, this will break previous migrations. Should I use native SQL to do the DB migrations, or rather the ActionController methods?

Comment: ActionController methods? Sure, you can delete a model-why not? Probably an irreversible migration, but that's fine.

Comment: I figured deleting Models would be bad after reading this: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1652025 (look at the "Never Use External Code in a Migration").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about breaking previous migrations.  Use the db/schema.rb or db/development_structure.sql file for importing the schema into a new database.

Go ahead and delete the models.  I would use native sql (the sql code generated by Rails migrations can be very inefficient in some cases).